# Buy token when liquidity is added using Proxy Contract

Tags: web3js, tokens, python, pancakeswap, proxy-contracts

I was checking that some tokens apply Bot prevention in the first minutes. In my case I am executing the contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens function to execute a purchase but if bot prevention is active, which would be the correct way to make the purchase. In any case, as valid with python if the purchase I made with the function was made correctly, taking into account that they use ContractProxy to avoid detecting liquidity.

Comment: What's the question? What bot are you talking about? What's the contract doing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.